# Replacing certain values in Python List

Tags: python, arrays, list, image-processing

I have created a list for displaying a black/white (binary) image with its pixel values. However for the calculations  I am running I can not work with 0s represented by the black pixels. I have been trying to convert the 0s to 1s with the following code but it  does not work despite producing no errors:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('C:/Users/binary.png', 'r')  
WIDTH, HEIGHT = img.size

data = list(img.getdata())  # convert image data to a list of integers
data = [data[offset:offset + WIDTH] for offset in range(0, WIDTH * HEIGHT, WIDTH)]

for (i, item) in enumerate(data):
    if item == 0:
        data[i] = 1

for row in data:
    print(' '.join('{:3}'.format(value) for value in row))
```

It might be noteworthy that when I try "item = 255" I get the following error: 
"TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'"

However this error doesn't make sense to me as when I do type(data) I get list output

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: try inserting a print(repr(item)) in your loop before the if. Maybe item is considered a string, and a not empty string isn't considered equal to 0, so you might never get in the if.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I have tried simply using print(data) which prints it as a continuous list as opposed to the "for row in data" line and the same issue occurs unfortunately

Comment: The first `for` loop expects `data` to be a 1-dimensional list, but the second loop expects it to be 2-dimensional.

Comment: @malmiteria what would be the expected outcome in this case?

Comment: I don't see `<` anywhere in the code, where is that error happening?

Comment: @Barmar apologises, should have been clearer. I was trying if item > 2 for example to try and change the 255 values instead

Comment: @Barmar even with the 2nd for loop removed and using "print(data)" the same problem occurs

Comment: print(repr(item)) should print the : 'item content' if it is a str and only : a number if it is a number. the quote are the important thing here.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a list of lists, you need nested loops.

```
for row in data:
    for i, value in enumerate(row):
        if value == 0:
            row[i] = 1
```